# Android 4.4.2. compilation error (wpa_supplicant_8)

Tags: android, ubuntu, compilation, makefile, arm

I recently acquire a UDOO Quad Board for Android development.

I'm trying to compile Android 4.4.2. from source files following the guide at:
http://www.udoo.org/docs/Advanced_Setup/Compile_Android_From_Sources

but with no exit.

My UDOO files are all at my home folder:
[udoo-android-dev] = guille@ubuntu:~/UDOO/UDOO_Android_4.4.2_Source_v1.0/4.4.2$

First of all, there is an issue, not a problematic one, at the executable setup at main folder.

Because setup is started with #!/bin/sh it's enable to use source neither lunch, because source is a special word for bash.
Solution: I changed #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash and it worked ok.

And then I get to the big problem:

when I do “make” at [udoo-android-dev] , compilation starts showing all includes but there are some “problematic” lines.

```
guille@ubuntu:~/UDOO/UDOO_Android_4.4.2_Source_v1.0/4.4.2$ make
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=udoo
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.19.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=1.0.4
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
…
including ./external/wpa_supplicant_8/Android.mk ...
external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/Android.mk:290: external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/src/drivers/drivers.mk: No such file or directory
…
including ./frameworks/base/Android.mk ...
find: `src': No such file or directory
…
including ./packages/apps/Camera2/Android.mk ...
fatal: Not a git repository: 'packages/apps/Camera2/.git'
…
build/core/Makefile:32: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/udoo/system/xbin/su'
build/core/base_rules.mk:529: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/udoo/system/xbin/su'
build/core/Makefile:32: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/udoo/system/etc/permissions/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml'
build/core/base_rules.mk:529: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/udoo/system/etc/permissions/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml'
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/fsl/sabresd_6dq/fstab.freescale:root/fstab.freescale ignored.
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE udoo
make: *** No rule to make target `external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/src/drivers/drivers.mk'.  Stop.
```

And there is no more compilation.

So the problem is that wpa_supplicant_8.

I've tried with the default cross_compiler indicated with setup executable and also with the cross compiler I downloaded from UDOO web.

Thanks for your time,
Guillermo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

beside installing multiple libraries 64 and 32 bits, my problem was that having more thean one version of Java(orcale 6, open 6 and open 7) It has to be selected oracle 6 for all Java modules (java, javac, javaws and the others).

I got other errors, but I did a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 over VMware workstation player, and after some tweaking did work.

Guillermo